# Build report from tortoise svn client

Tags: svn, reporting

I am looking for a solution to build release notes from svn. What I want is a command line utility or something which can get me all the comments of checked in files from a given date.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
svn log -r {2008-05-28}:{2008-12-31}
```

from inside the working copy.

(See the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) for details)

---

Clarification: I believe Tortoisesvn doesn't bring a set of svn command-line binaries with it. You will need to install the [Subversion package from here](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Comment: Thanks all for the info.

But I dont see svn.exe in c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\ folder. Where can I get this utility?

Answer (score 2):

You can get that using the svn command line tools and the log command:

`svn log svn://server/repos/trunk -r HEAD:{2009-02-19}`

If you want, you can also get an XML formatted output.

see also the SVN Book section on [Revision Dates](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch03s03.html#svn-ch-3-sect-3.3)